# App crashes as array size increases

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an empty iOS application. The only code is creation of two arrays.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    uint8_t pixelData[360 * 360 * 4];
    uint8_t sapixelData[360 * 360 * 4];
}
```

When I run the application on an iPad air 2 it crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS code 1.

Suppose I reduce the size of the array to the following,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    uint8_t pixelData[60 * 360 * 4];
    uint8_t sapixelData[60 * 360 * 4];
}
```

the app does not crash. My requirement demands that the array be of size 360 * 360 * 4. Please help me solve this crash. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't allocate on the stack, as that can have limited size.  Instead use the heap and remember to `free()` the memory afterwards:

```
uint8_t *pixelData = malloc(60 * 360 * 4);
uint8_t *sapixelData = malloc(60 * 360 * 4);

...

free(sapixelData);
free(pixelData);
```

Better still use `NSMutableData` as that will clean-up after itself:

```
NSMutableData *pixelData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:60 * 360 * 4];
NSMutableData *sapixelData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:60 * 360 * 4];
```